# EEVEE viewport and render are completely different

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, hair

I am creating this scene with hair in EEVEE - but the viewport and the render are completely different. I am using Bloom, turbulence force field. I can't seem to understand why this error occurs.

Viewport[image]

Render:
[image]

.blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a particle system with hair and interpolated children.

Interpolated children in particle childrens have a *count* property which is different for viewport and render.

[image: render amount]

If you want the same amount of children (and the same results) for display and render, choose the same value for *Display Amount* amd *Render Amount*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't notice that.